# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'favicon.ico'

Tags: python, django

I am building a BlogApp and I was working on a Feature and Suddenly i saw an Error while server is running. It shows below ↓ Error when i open something in browser.

Everything is Working Fine BUT this is keep showing in every Click i do.

> ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'favicon.ico'.

views.py

```
def detail_view(request,id):
    data = get_object_or_404(Post,id=id)
    comments = data.comments.order_by('-created_at')
    new_comment = None
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=id)

    if post.allow_comments == True :
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                comment_form.instance.post_by = data
                comment_form.instance.commented_by = request.user
                comment_form.instance.active = True
                new_comment = comment_form.save()
                return redirect('detail_view',id=id)

        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

    context = {'counts':data.likes.count,'post':post,'data':data,'comments':comments,'new_comment':new_comment,'comment_form':comment_form}
    return render(request, 'show_more.html', context )
```

urls.py

```
path('<id>',views.detail_view,name='detail_view'),
```

```
**When i check this Error in Browser, it is showing `data = get_object_or_404(Post,id=id) ` IT MEANS that the error is in this line in Views.py.**

I don't know what's wrong in this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.
```

Comment: Try changing `id` with `pk` because **id** is a built-in function in python.

Comment: I changed   data = get_object_or_404(Post,`pk`=id) BUT it is keep showing that Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```py
# urls.py
path('<int:pk>',views.detail_view,name='detail_view'),
```

and in your `views.py`:

```py
def detail_view(request,id):
    data = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    # ......
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    #......
        return redirect('detail_view',pk=pk)
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I just notice that you are making an extra query to a database. Because data and post variables storing the same value in them.

Comment: I really appreciate your Effort, BUT it is keep showing this Error. I have also removed the other variable

Comment: It is also showing `The above exception (invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'favicon.ico') was the direct cause of the following exception:`

Comment: Ok! then kindly add your template file to your question. Because I think the problem is in your template.

Comment: I have added the template

Comment: IT worked. When i close the server AND start it again. IT WORKED

Comment: Glad to hear this ;)